# Unity - send object / return assetbundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have a script to export a gameobject in runtime. What I want to do is send that object to another unity editor, create an asset bundle and return it (to any location on my pc), all by just clicking a button on my app, via script. Is there a way to do it?

I have seen people using batchmode but I dont know how to pass an object to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `I dont know how to pass an object to it.` .. object of what kind? In general you can just have a batch/shell script to place the object into a very specific location (path) your bundle app is pre-configured /coded to load from + maybe some meta data for desired output name and location so you can retrieve it when finished

Comment: It's a 3d object, my app exports it to desktop. What i need is to trigger a unity editor to create an asset bundle from my app, using that exported 3d object

Comment: so what hinders you to upload it into a specific location like `YOURBUNDLEAPP/Assets/ModelToImport.fbx` (or whatever your model format is) .. and then tell your app to simply always import the FBX stored in that location

Comment: I can do that, but the problem i have is how to pass the object to BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle to create a bundle of that object. It is supposed to do from the app, so clicking in the editor is not an option

Comment: afaik [`BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles.html) example shows a couple of ways how to find and add assets to them ... and via [`-executeMethod` command line argument](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditorCommandLineArguments.html) you can automate just any method call from the console the same as if it was called via a click within the editor ...